# how can i import from HDFS using sqoop and combine two columns of the table while importing?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, sqoop2

Can I combine two or more columns while importing or exporting suppose i have 3 columns in DBMS ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME and i want to load it as ID,NAME only two columns. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Try the below option

```
sqoop import --connect <db server> --username <user> --password <password> --query "select ID,CONCAT(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME) from table" --target-dir <hdfs directory>
```

Since you have'nt mentioned your database and table name I have written in generic form.

Comment: thanks for reply i have tried it, but its giving only 0's in that column

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?. please provide the query for further analysis. Before running the query with sqoop run the query directly on database and check the query output.

Comment: i am using MySQL it giving me same output all 0's in the same column i wrote select ID, fName+lName from employee; from termonal in ubuntu still it gives 0's in fName+lName column

Comment: Since you have not mentioned about your Database I gave generic concat syntax, But I beleive my answer is correct. Does it solved your problem?.

Answer (score 0):

thanks srinivasan got the solution

```
sqoop import --connect <db server> --username <user> --password <password> --query "select ID,concat(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME) from table" --target-dir <hdfs directory>
```